# How do BCAA's promote faster muscle recovery?

Tags: proteins, muscles

I am aware that ingesting Branched chain amino acids (BCAA's) prior, during, and after workouts has an effect on muscle recovery due to their difficulty of metabolism. However, how much more efficiently do they speed up recovery versus whey proteins for example?

Comment: What are BCAAs? Please define acronyms when posting questions (and answers) here.

Comment: "Branched chain amino acids" (valine, isoleucine, leucine) is the general understanding.

Comment: Branched chain amino acids. @MattDMo